# Solve Ax = b when the dimension of b does not equal the dimension of A

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, matrix-equations

I am having trouble solving part b of this problem. I was able to solve part a, however, when I try to solve `Ax = b` and `Ay =c` I do not see how I can set up an augmented matrix and row reduce. The dimension of `b` and `c` are 4 but the dimension of the vectors in `A` are 3.

Does anybody know how to solve this?

Should I add a zero vector as the last row of `A`?

[image]

Comment: If $x$ is compatible with $A$ then $Ax$ has three rows.  It is impossible to solve these equations.

Comment: So is this a typo or a trick question?

Comment: I would say so.

Comment: Unless you can write one of the coordinates in terms of the other three. I don't see a solution

Answer (score 1):

There must be a typo.

$A \in \mathbb{R}^{3 \times 3}$, $x \in \mathbb{R}^{3 \times 1}$, hence $Ax \in \mathbb{R}^{3 \times 1}$ and it cannot be equal to a vector of length $4$.